# Given a point, how can I query SQL Server to find the stored polygons that encompass it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, spatial, wkt

Given a point, how can I query SQL Server to find the stored polygons that encompass it?

I have a database table that has the polygons of all 50 US states.  I need a query that will allow me to search for which states are within 90 miles of that point.

Here is my table structure and data for three states:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.States (
State varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CoordinatorEmail varchar(255) NULL,
Borders geography(-1) NULL
);

INSERT INTO States (State, Borders) 
VALUES ('Alaska', (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-141.0205 70.0187,-141.7291 70.1292,-144.8163 70.4515,-148.4583 70.7471,-151.1609 70.7923,-152.6221 71.1470,-153.9954 71.1185,-154.8853 71.4307,-156.7529 71.5232,-157.9449 71.2796,-159.6313 71.2249,-161.8671 70.6363,-163.5809 70.0843,-165.2399 69.3028,-166.8768 69.1782,-168.0414 68.3344,-165.9155 67.6844,-164.6082 67.2933,-164.0149 66.7789,-165.7507 66.5810,-167.5745 66.2867,-168.9862 66.0269,-168.9478 65.4970,-167.4756 65.0420,-167.0142 64.3922,-165.7343 64.0554,-163.2294 64.0193,-162.1143 63.9615,-163.6029 63.6877,-165.3717 63.4530,-166.3715 62.4133,-166.9867 61.6534,-166.4429 60.8556,-167.8381 60.5357,-167.7118 59.5482,-165.8002 59.4115,-164.5972 59.3696,-162.8558 59.1168,-162.5427 58.1185,-160.6421 58.1359,-159.5050 58.0285,-158.8953 57.6336,-159.9060 56.9090,-160.6531 56.3926,-161.8835 56.2342,-162.9822 55.7240,-164.3994 55.2478,-165.3168 54.7753,-167.1075 54.1463,-168.5852 53.5632,-169.9146 53.1402,-169.5959 52.5964,-168.2227 52.9089,-162.7734 54.2139,-159.1452 54.6786,-155.4634 55.6567,-152.1400 57.3510,-150.8203 59.2209,-147.4461 59.7695,-145.9850 60.3521,-144.1544 59.8917,-141.6811 59.8172,-140.5124 59.5225,-138.8548 59.0292,-136.8526 57.9032,-136.0725 56.9157,-134.9794 56.1555,-134.0057 55.3237,-133.6418 54.6341,-130.6261 54.7135,-129.9930 55.2869,-130.0108 55.9869,-130.1083 56.1057,-131.5887 56.6086,-132.8755 57.8404,-133.8423 58.7276,-134.9121 59.3108,-135.4724 59.8020,-136.3445 59.6039,-136.8251 59.1619,-137.6079 59.2441,-139.2119 60.0902,-139.0938 60.3575,-140.0056 60.1866,-140.9999 60.3059,-141.0205 70.0187,-141.0205 70.0187))', 4326)));


INSERT INTO States (State, Borders) 
VALUES ('Alabama', (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-88.1955 35.0041,-85.6068 34.9918,-85.1756 32.8404,-84.8927 32.2593,-85.0342 32.1535,-85.1358 31.7947,-85.0438 31.5200,-85.0836 31.3384,-85.1070 31.2093,-84.9944 31.0023,-87.6009 30.9953,-87.5926 30.9423,-87.6256 30.8539,-87.4072 30.6745,-87.3688 30.4404,-87.5240 30.1463,-88.3864 30.1546,-88.4743 31.8939,-88.1021 34.8938,-88.1721 34.9479,-88.1461 34.9107,-88.1955 35.0041))', 4326)));


INSERT INTO States (State, Borders) 
VALUES ('Arkansas', (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-94.0416 33.0225,-91.2057 33.0075,-91.1989 33.1180,-91.1041 33.1824,-91.1343 33.3053,-91.1646 33.4211,-91.2263 33.4337,-91.2524 33.5403,-91.1797 33.6112,-91.2524 33.6855,-91.1261 33.6946,-91.1412 33.7883,-91.0451 33.7700,-91.0341 33.8328,-91.0863 33.9399,-90.9256 34.0208,-90.9036 34.0856,-90.9586 34.1345,-90.9132 34.1675,-90.8501 34.1380,-90.9325 34.2311,-90.6935 34.3446,-90.5603 34.4409,-90.5548 34.5348,-90.5768 34.5959,-90.5301 34.7213,-90.5328 34.7574,-90.4546 34.8780,-90.3529 34.8454,-90.2911 34.8690,-90.3104 35.0255,-90.2843 35.1154,-90.1772 35.1323,-90.1112 35.1985,-90.1524 35.2826,-90.1332 35.4383,-90.0206 35.5579,-89.9780 35.6740,-89.9547 35.7287,-89.6594 35.9169,-89.6883 35.9658,-89.7130 36.0013,-90.3735 35.9958,-90.2664 36.1268,-90.0934 36.2875,-90.0742 36.3892,-90.1511 36.4180,-90.1566 36.4997,-94.6198 36.4986,-94.4412 35.3801,-94.4893 33.6318,-94.4522 33.6421,-94.4000 33.5597,-94.2462 33.5883,-94.1885 33.5872,-94.0375 33.5345,-94.0430 33.4314,-94.0430 33.0213,-94.0416 33.0225))', 4326)));
```

I have been trying the following query just to make sure I can get the state of the point (without yet worrying about the 90 mile radius), but I haven't figure this part out yet.

```
DECLARE @LittleRock geography;
SET @LittleRock = geography::Point(34.742000, -92.276543, 4326);

Select State from States 
where States.Borders.STIntersects(@LittleRock) = 1;

SELECT State from States 
where States.Borders.STContains(@LittleRock) = 1;
```

Neither `STIntersets()` nor `STContains()` returns anything.  Thoughts?

Comment: Within 90 miles of what point exactly? each boundary point? can you be more specific?

Comment: @DanielMarcus, any given point really.  But the one I provided as an example is Little Rock.

Comment: right but little rock consists of many points - i would take an arbitrary spot on the graph of the state and run the distance formula to see what is  90 miles away

Comment: The point that I will check will differ.  For now I'm just trying to get a dataset of the states that contain the given point.  So it *should* only return Arkansas for the LittleRock point given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code on my local instance, I got the following error (abbreviated):

> This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid.
>   Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance.

Next, I did what the robot told me to do:

```
UPDATE dbo.States
SET Borders = Borders.MakeValid();
```

Once that was done, I was able to determine that Little Rock is indeed in Arkansas with both `STIntersects()` and `STContains()`. So there was *something* malformed in at least one of your geography instances.

**EDIT**

Given the OPs full data set, it has another issue with some of the states. Specifically, 21 states appear to have a ring orientation problem. With Geography polygons, the order in which you specify the vertexes is important. I never remember whether clockwise or counter-clockwise is the right direction. But I *do* remember the heuristic I use. If the envelope angle for the polygon is greater than 90°, I probably got it wrong. Luckily, that is also easy to correct for.

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Borders = s.Borders.ReorientObject()
FROM dbo.States AS s
WHERE s.Borders.EnvelopeAngle() > 90
```

With the raw data set, your Little Rock query returns 22 states. With the update above run, it returns only Arkansas.

Comment: With that small set it does look like it worked, but when I tried this against the entire set it returned about 50% false positives.  Here's the full dataset: https://gist.github.com/JoshuaCarroll/5e95b2610d0bba01de741b2e95868a26

Comment: @Joshua: I've edited my answer to account for what appears to be a problem with your data.

Comment: I'm completely serious when I ask for your Patreon, Facebook or Venmo... I'm buying you a beer!

Comment: Lol. Nah… Pay it forward. I am curious where you got the WKT for the states though. Whenever I answer one of these questions, I'm hard pressed to come up with something good/real-world.

Comment: I actually made the WKT.  I found an XML of the border points (1), then I created an XSL transform (2) to give me the WKT (3). 

1. https://gist.github.com/JoshuaCarroll/0560ffb9822e81c9d6fad356215e7a7a

2. https://gist.github.com/JoshuaCarroll/d2efe2b9f1f65af39d5665c53e63a16b

3. https://gist.github.com/JoshuaCarroll/49630cbeeb254a49986e939a26672e9c